# How do you obtain a pointer to the element that two arrays don't have in common?

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is my code:

```
#include <algorithm>
void f() {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int b[] = {1, 2, 100, 101};
    // I want to do something like this:
    // int* found = compare(a[0], a[3], b[0]);
    // in order to get a pointer to a[2]
}
```

Maybe I've missed this algorithm in the manual.

Comment: `int[] a`? Where's the C++ code. Do you mean "compare two vectors" or "compare two arrays".

Comment: are you trying to find out the last matching index on both arrays?
and in case first element is not matching you would return an error code or a 0?

Comment: I think these are arrays, not vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) your array and use [mismatch](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/mismatch/).

Answer (score 6):

Look at [std::mismatch](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/mismatch/)