# Comparing two arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I've two arrays, say A = {1,2,3,4,5} and B = {5,6,3,4,5}. I want to compare the two arrays and tell how many elements in A are lesser than B and vice versa and also possibly the elements position which are lesser. I can do this using nested loop but is there a efficient way in C++ to do this ?

In this example,
A = {1,2,3,4,5}
B = {5,6,3,4,5}

So I expect the answer to be "B is greater than A" just because it satisfies the condition that it is greater in two elements. or if it is

A = {1,2,3,4,5} and B = {1,2,3,0,4}, A is greater.

I need to compare only the number if elements greater or lesser and not the values in itself.

Sorry for my ambiguity.

Comment: If you post your inefficient code we can help you improve it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903394/how-to-compare-two-vectors-in-c

Comment: Three out of four answer so far aren't sure about what you mean. Take this as a hint to improve your question by specifying exactly what you want.

Comment: I'm amazed you got 5 answers to such a vague, poorly worded, and utterly incomprehensible question.  Clarify the question and you will get much better answers.

Comment: I think this question demonstrates so throughly why I think that programmers _should_ be required to learn some abstract mathematics. It is with the language of mathematics that questions like this can be communicated very effectively and precisely.

Comment: You need to decide whether this is a `C` question or a `C++` question.

Comment: This is the first time I ever saw a '-6' question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to compare corresponding elements of A and B and count how many A' are less than the matching B's? This can be done with std::inner_product like this:

```
int A[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
int B[] = { 5,6,3,4,5 };

int count = std::inner_product(A, A+5, B, 0, std::plus<int>(), std::less<int>());

std::cout << count << "\n";
```

Of course, this just an O(n) loop inside the STL numeric algorithm.

Comment: This looks simple and efficient but is it possible to say how many elements are smaller, greater or equal? Thanks.

Comment: @Sunil: In this case, it only counts how many times the relation `std::less<int>()` is true. For a different result, the last parameter can be changed to any one of the `<functional>` binary predicates such as `equal_to`, `not_equal_to`, `greater`, `less`, `greater_equal`, `less_equal`, or a user-provided function object.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean. Do you mean compare them element-wise?

```
vector<int> indexesForA;
vector<int> indexesForB;
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if(A[i] < B[i]) {
        indexesForA.push_back(i);
    }
    else if(B[i] < A[i]) {
        indexesForB.push_back(i);
    }
}

// now indexesForA.size() is the count of indexes i where A[i] < B[i]
// and indexesForA contains the indexes
// similarly for indexesForB
```

Please post a clarification and we can guide you.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. I was wondering if there would be an efficient way instead of using for and if conditions because if I have thousands of arrays to compare then this would take forever. It is also very important that orders don't change so sorting would not work.

Comment: @Sunil: This is `O(n)`. You can't asymptotically do any better.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my example. Maybe it could be using more advanced STL techniques but I think this suffices.

```
class Examiner
{
    template <class Pred>
    struct CompareToZero: std::unary_function<const int&, bool> {
        Pred comparator;
        bool operator() (const int& value) const {
            return comparator(value, 0);
        }
    };
    template<class T>
    std::vector<size_t> getComparedIndices(const CompareToZero<T>& comparator, const std::vector<int>& vint) const {
        std::vector<size_t> retval;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < vint.size(); i++) {
            if (comparator(vint[i]))
                retval.push_back(i);
        }
        return retval;
    }
    const std::vector<int>& _results;

public:
    Examiner(const std::vector<int>& results)
        : _results(results) {
    }

    std::vector<size_t> getLessIndices() const {        
        return getComparedIndices(CompareToZero<std::less<int> >(), _results);
    }
    std::vector<size_t> getGreaterIndices() const {
        return getComparedIndices(CompareToZero<std::greater<int> >(), _results);
    }
    std::vector<size_t> getEqualIndices() const {
        return getComparedIndices(CompareToZero<std::equal_to<int> >(), _results);
    }
    size_t getLessCount() const {
        return getLessIndices().size();
    }
    size_t getGreaterCount() const {
        return getGreaterIndices().size();
    }
    size_t getEqualCount() const {
        return getEqualIndices().size();
    }
};


void arrcomp()
{
    int A[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int B[5] = {5,6,3,2,4};

    std::vector<int> results(sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
        results[i] =
            (A[i] < B[i])? -1:
                (A[i] > B[i])? 0:
                    1;            
    }
    Examiner examiner(results);

    std::cout << "less count   : " << examiner.getLessCount() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "greater count: " << examiner.getGreaterCount() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "equal count  : " << examiner.getEqualCount() << std::endl;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int A[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int B[5] = {5,6,3,2,4};

std::vector<int> vectA(A);
std::vector<int> vectB(B);
```

and using std `<algorithm>` to do the job or part of the job on the two vectors.

for example:
count_if     Return number of elements in range satisfying condition (function template)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean?  Do you mean where A[i] < B[i] or do you mean how many elements in B are less than A[i]?  Either you'll have a single loop where you're comparing the ith element of each array, or you'll have a nested loop where you're comparing the ith element of A with the jth element of B.  Since I don't know which one you want, I can't tell you the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient way is to sort the arrays first and then just check in which index is the first element of array B that is greater than its A counterpart. As the ordering is transitive, you can even do it for all the elements in the same pass.